# Session captcha is always wrong

Tags: php

here is the link to the captcha code that im using [click here](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/simple-php-captcha/) The problem is when I post the captcha code it always say its incorrect when Im doing my verification.
it always shows the error message so its not validating properly how do i use the session['captcha']['code'] without it messing up every post back
 Something is wrong like it must change after post back and is different in the session but when i print($_SESSION) the value is there for the captcha to be entered and matched.

PHP: all on the same page.

```
<?PHP 
session_start();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = captcha();
$captcha_code = $_POST["captcha_code"];

if(isset($_POST["captcha_code"]) ){
    do verification here //
    if(....) {
        if(strtolower($captcha_code) !=  strtolower($_SESSION["captcha"]["code"])) {                

            $error_message .= "<li>The code you entered is incorrect.</li>";    
            $hasError = true;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the session after checking the post! This way you create a new session before you compare it with the posted. Thats way its always wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't verify the contents of the captcha.php file - I can't help much with your issue. However, this is a possibility.

Your $_SESSION['captcha'] = captcha(); seems incorrect to me {because I can't find the source for captcha.php}. If it's setting the session on the same page load as a form being posted, how are you sure it's not a different captcha session being set when you use the print_r($_SESSION) call? If you know what I mean. In your captcha() function (captcha.php file), is it setting the session there as well, without confirming a false post? Thus, changing on page load of a $_POST? In other words - is it ensuring it doesn't "reset" when the form is posted before validating the users input.

Where is the captcha.php code?

Also, you seem to be missing include("captcha.php"); after the session_start(); call. That may be your issue right there. But, can't confirm.